# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar la operación en multiplicar dentro de un Datatable en primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Buenos días tengo un inconveniente con el `datatable` en **primefaces** al momento de realizar la operación de multiplicar el campo precio con el campo cantidad donde el total no es el correspondiente y el monto total si lo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el código o en que estoy fallando:

```
public void agregar() {
    totalpedido=0;
    subtotalpedido=0;

    DetallePedido det=new DetallePedido();
    Medicamentos medi=new Medicamentos();
    det.setCantidaddetallepedido(cantidad);
    det.setTotalpedido(totalpedido);
    det.setMedicamentos(medicamentos);
    this.lista.add(det);
    for(DetallePedido det1 : lista) {
        //   medi.setPreciocosto(cantidad);
        det1.setSubtotalpedido(subtotalpedido);
        subtotalpedido = det1.getMedicamentos().getPreciocosto()*det1.getCantidaddetallepedido();
    totalpedido += det1.getMedicamentos().getPreciocosto()*det1.getCantidaddetallepedido();
    }
}



   <p:dataTable id="detalle" value="#{pedidoBean.lista}"    var="det"  paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}  {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

                    <p:column headerText="Proveedor">
                        #{det.medicamentos.proveedor.nomproveedor}
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Nombre Producto">
                        #{det.medicamentos.nommedicamento}
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Precio">
                        #{det.medicamentos.preciocosto}
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Cantidad">
                        #{det.cantidaddetallepedido}
                    </p:column>
                   <p:column headerText="Total">
                        #{pedidoBean.subtotalpedido}
                    </p:column>

                    <p:columnGroup type="footer">
                      <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="4" style="text-align:right" footerText="Monto Total:" />
                        <p:column footerText="$#{pedidoBean.totalpedido}" />

                      </p:row>
                    </p:columnGroup>

                </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código facelets que utilizas para mostrar la tabla. Creo que el problema es que estás utilizando `#{tuBean.subtotalPedido}` cuando debería ser `#{fila.subtotalPedido}`.

Comment: Buenas Tardes Luiggi este es el bean <p:column headerText="Total">
                            #{pedidoBean.subtotalpedido}
                        </p:column>

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta (utiliza el enlace que dice **editar** debajo del texto) y agrega todo el código facelets necesario para reproducir tu problema, esto es: `<p:datatable value="..." var="..."> <p:column> .... <p:column> ....` y demás.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás utilizando el campo de subtotal que tienes definido en el bean cuando deberías usar el campo de subtotal definido en cada objeto que usas como fila. El código problemático es este:

```
<p:column headerText="Total">
    #{pedidoBean.subtotalpedido}
</p:column>
```

Para resolverlo, deberías cambiar el codigo a esta manera:

```
<p:column headerText="Total">
    #{det.subtotalpedido}
</p:column>
```

Asimismo, debes cambiar el orden de asignación de subtotal:

```
for(DetallePedido det1 : lista) {
    subtotalpedido = det1.getMedicamentos().getPreciocosto()*det1.getCantidaddetallepedido();
    //la asignación debe ser luego del cálculo
    det1.setSubtotalpedido(subtotalpedido);
totalpedido += det1.getMedicamentos().getPreciocosto()*det1.getCantidaddetallepedido();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la columna con el encabezado "Total" deberías hacer la multiplicación, así:

```
<p:column headerText="Total">
    #{det.medicamentos.preciocosto * det.cantidaddetallepedido}
</p:column>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas sencillo para eso es modifica tu clase DetallePedido y realiza la multiplicación dentro del getSubtotalpedido. de esta forma.

```
public float getSubtotalpedido()
{
this.getPreciocosto()*this.getCantidaddetallepedido();
}
```